# How can a wasteland be "washed in somewhat queasy-ugly bleached orange"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I was very confused when I came across a sentence in “[The body politic](http://movies.nytimes.com/2012/06/29/movies/magic-mike-by-steven-soderbergh-with-channing-tatum.html)” in New York Times (June 28)

> Set in Tampa (but also shot in California), a palm-lined wasteland that Mr. Soderbergh has washed in somewhat queasy-ugly bleached orange, the movie opens at the club with the owner-M.C., Dallas (a spectacular, amusingly sleazed-out Matthew McConaughey), running down
>   the rules for the female clientele.

I think "bleached orange" is some kind of color. Wash a wasteland in a color, in a movie, what does that mean? I'm totally confused.

I also failed to find  "sleazed-out"  in dictionaries.  I know *sleaze* means  tastelessness by virtue of being cheap and vulgar.  but what does "sleazed-out"  mean?

Comment: This should probably be two different questions. Good question though. +1

Answer (score 12):

Soderbergh is a cinematographer. The "bleached orange" is probably a filter he has added to the film to tint the backgrounds in order to produce some sort of effect in the viewer.

"Sleazed-out" means that Matt McConaughey (who is generally clean-cut and good-looking) has been made to look like a [sleaze](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sleaze?s=t).

Comment: Agreed, the 'bleached orange' would be referring to the colour palette that was used in the movie.  The reviewer is basically saying that the visual style and coloring of the movie was overly washed-out (desaturated) and orange-tinted, and pretty ugly by the sounds of it.

Comment: @JesseM Yes, well said.

Comment: A non-native english speaker might not know that in this sense to "wash" is to apply a color tint.  In decorative/artistic terms, a "wash" and a "glaze" are similar.

Comment: @Bob yes, good point.

Comment: Whenever I hear "wash" in this context, I think of a thin watercolor paint, and the way an artist applies a "wash" for a certain effect. The filter on the camera does similarly.